Using graph-api: inviting external user fails with "The invited user already exists in the directory..." but they are not in users
I am checking whether a requested user exists in my tenant by using
graphClient.Users.GetAsync(r => r.QueryParameters =
            new UsersRequestBuilder.UsersRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters()
            {
                Filter = $"Mail eq '{email}'"
            });

(I have also run this using the graphapi explorer and get the same result)
It returns an empty array indicating the user doesnt exist
So, I go ahead and invite them
using
var invitation = new Invitation
{
    InvitedUserEmailAddress = userModel.Email,
    SendInvitationMessage = true,
    InvitedUserDisplayName = $"{userModel.FirstName} {userModel.LastName}",
    InviteRedirectUrl = redirectUrl,
    InvitedUserType = "guest"
};
    var invite = await graphClient
        .Invitations
        .PostAsync(invitation);

but I get
The invited user already exists in the directory as object ID:
back from this call.
No user with this email address exists in the tenant that I have passed when initialising the GraphServiceCLient, eg
var authProvider = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, appClientId, secret.Value);      
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

The user does exist in Entra (in another Tenant we are using), but not in this Tenant.

Also, if I grab the objectid from the invitation failure, and use it to call
graphClient.Users[userEntraId].AppRoleAssignments.PostAsync to invite that user to my application, I get an error back Resource ' ' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

To check if the user exists, I used the below code:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var clientId = "ClientID";
        var tenantId = "TenantID";
        var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";

        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);

        string email = "rukmini@gmail.com";

        try
        {
            var user = await graphClient.Users[email].GetAsync();

            if (user != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"User with email '{email}' exists.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"User with email '{email}' does not exist.");
            }
        }
        catch (ODataError odataError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}


To invite the user, used the below code:
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var clientId = "ClientID";
        var tenantId = "TenantID";
        var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
        
        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);

        var invitedUserEmailAddress = "rukmini@gmail.com";
        var invitedUserDisplayName = "Rukmini";

        var redirectUrl = "https://myapp.contoso.com"; 

        var invitationRequest = new Invitation
        {
            InvitedUserEmailAddress = invitedUserEmailAddress,
            SendInvitationMessage = true,
            InvitedUserDisplayName = invitedUserDisplayName,
            InviteRedirectUrl = redirectUrl,
            InvitedUserType = "guest"
        };

        try
        {
            var result = await graphClient.Invitations.PostAsync(invitationRequest);
            Console.WriteLine("Invitation created successfully.");
        }
        catch (ODataError odataError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}


The user invited successfully:


The error "The invited user already exists in the directory..." usually occurs if the user is already present in the tenant.

Check if the user has been invited previously but not yet accepted the invitation.
Check the existence of the user in the current tenant and make sure you are passing correct tenant ID.
If the user doesn't exist in the tenant and you still get the error, it's possible there's a lingering invitation for the user that hasn't been accepted.
You can try cleanup of such invitations before attempting to invite the user again.


Sorry for delay, had to leave this for a little while.

So, we have a number of tenants, with a parent tenancy, and typically the user exists in the main tenancy, and can be invited into one of the others.  ANd these API calls I made work as expected.
But, I'm finding that some users are problematic, and even cant be added in the Entra portal itself.  Entra gives me error "User Invitation failed" "Non-existent user already exists with the given email address ad cant be invited".
I cant find a user with the same email in the child Tenancy, but they do exist in the parent Tenancy.

I do the following to find the user by email:
graphClient.Users.GetAsync(r => r.QueryParameters =                 new UsersRequestBuilder.UsersRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters()                 {                     Filter = $"Mail eq '{email}'"                 })
Which works fine usually, but not for some users, and not for aliases of users that are already in the Tenant, ie it returns null, ie that they are NOT found (correctly), but its adding them that fails
